# Decode bplist string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to parse values from a JSON file using javascript. Using getJSON method, I was able to get values from the JSON.

**Q1: On reaching the attributedString, I'm unable to get values beyond this point. I tried using the below code. But it throws error**

```
var sample = data.layers[i].layers[j].attributedString._class;
console.log(sample)
```

[Link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wq2khhos/)

On googling I found that some values are given in base 64 bplist format.

**Q2: How can I decode the bplist format values to a readable format using Javascript?.**

I found a node package that does the above. But I would like to have it in a javascript browserified format. Thanks

[Node Module](https://github.com/joeferner/node-bplist-parser), [Another One](https://github.com/pi-chan/bplist-parser)

Answer (score 0):

You had errors because some values were `undefined`, you just have to test it before accessing sub values :

```js
var page = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ca2vz'
$.getJSON(page, function(data) {
  var layerNo = data.layers.length;
  for (i = 0; i < layerNo; i++) {
    var slideName = data.layers[i].name
    var slideConNo = data.layers[i].layers.length;
    for (j = 0; j < slideConNo; j++) {
      var layerName = data.layers[i].layers[j].name
      var as = data.layers[i].layers[j].attributedString;

      if (as) {
        var sample = data.layers[i].layers[j].attributedString._class;
        console.log('sample =', sample)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how to decode the bplist format values?

Comment: @JinsonJohny I don't know, but if this is base64 or if you need to decode base64, you can use [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob)